# Quick Sort vs Selection Sort (Java vs C++)

Tags: java, c++, compare, quicksort

I created two projects. One in C++ and one in Java. I did time trials for a QuickSort and SelectionSort for both. Oddly enough I found some very strange behavior.

Here were the results for an array of size 10,000:

SelectionSort Java: 80 ms

SelectionSort C++: 2914 ms

QuickSort Java: 1 ms

QuickSort C++: ~45 seconds

Now call me crazy but I've always been taught that QuickSort is the fastest. This proves to be true in Java yet in C++ it completely gets shut down.

**So my question is, does C++ handle QuickSort differently?**

I tried to keep the functions the same between languages and they are exactly the same with the exception of using a vector in C++ vs an int array. I'd prefer to use a vector anyway because the actual project I want to use the sort for in C++ requires a vector.

I'm sure it's a dumb mistake or something I'm making but please provide some insight as to why this is happening.

EDIT:

I believe I see what the problem is. Thanks everyone for the extremely fast responses. I'll be modifying my code to work as intended. I knew it was a simple mistake. Also, although the question asked is quite embarrassing, the responses are educational.

Comment: use a `Vector` in Java. You're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: How are you compiling your C++ code? Do you have optimizations turned on?

Comment: I'm just compiling it in Visual Studio, default settings, I don't believe I have optimizations turned on. Also the final compiler I will be using for timed results won't be under my control.

Comment: It is worth noting that quick sort is not guaranteed to be the fastest. In the worst case this algorithm makes O(n*n) comparisons. If you want to be guaranteed O(n*logn) use merge sort instead.

Comment: @Timlankey: Nobody who cares about the performance of their program would compile with optimizations off. The performance of a non-optimized build is irrelevant and all release builds have all optimizations turned on.

Answer (score 18):

Your quicksort function returns your entire vector by value on every recursive call, even though the function modifies it in place. Probably returning all those temporaries and then throwing them away hurts performance.

Just change the function to `void` and remove the ending return and see how it behaves.

EDIT: If you're more used to Java where almost everything is garbage collected references, note that in C++ a return by value (as you have on the return type) typically makes a copy of whatever is being returned. And as @Johannes Schaub - litb points out the compiler isn't even able to optimize the return away because it's not returning an automatic (local) variable.

EDIT2: If you aren't doing this as an exercise however you should use either `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort` (the latter if you know your data will already be almost sorted, or you need to preserve the order of duplicates). For example `std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());`

Comment: See the problem is that the reason why I am sorting stuff is because I will need to reuse that sorted array in the main function (not shown in the code I provided)

Comment: And no NRVO is possible here, because he's not returning an automatic variable.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I really appreciate the help and using std::sort does seem like my best option.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a complete vector on every recursive call. This takes a lot of time (99,99% of the time spent copying).

By the way, you can use the STL sort function in C++, it's guaranteed to be a quicksort (though this will mess up your profiling because you're not doing a true comparison).

#### EDIT:

Apparently `std::sort` is not guaranteed to be quicksort, but it is guaranteed to be O(n*log(n)). [Source](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html#2)

Comment: What do you mean the quicksort in C++ is wrong? Unless I linked the wrong file, it's the same as the java one just using a vector instead of an int. 

If I completely got the algorithm wrong for quicksort, please let me know. I want to be able to program a sort in C++ that can average O(nlogn)

Comment: @Timlankey: Use `std::sort`, it is O(nlogn).

Comment: std::sort is not guaranteed to be quicksort. It is guaranteed to be O(n Log n)

Comment: +1 nice catch. @Timlankey: just remove the return from the `quicksort` function and that will speed the operation quite a bit. @nightcracker: `std::sort` is usually introsort, which is a variant around quicksort that tries to avoid the horrible worst case performance.

Comment: @David Rodriguez: I'm sorry, I remembered it wrong. It is guaranteed to be O(n*log(n)) though.

Comment: @Timlankey: BTW, the reason that returning the vector does not have that performance impact in Java is that it works with references, rather than value types, and that means that only the reference (a pointer is copied).

Comment: I'm trying that now by making it void. Unfortunately, that won't be useful to me when I need that final vector. However, if std::sort does guarantee to be O(nlogn) then that might just be sufficient enough.

Comment: @Timlankey: You passed the vector in by reference. There is no final vector- only one vector ever exists, and once you call quicksort on it, then it's sorted- no returning needed.

Answer (score 2):

There's yet another issue with your C++ code that nobody seems to have pointed out yet. If we get rid of the timing code, it becomes pretty obvious though:

```
quicksort(A,0,length - 1);

SelectionSort(A,length);
```

You're doing the selection sort on data that's already sorted. Under the circumstances, it probably doesn't make a huge difference, but still helps some. If you used an insertion sort, it would show up as practically instantaneous.

Comment: Yea I noticed that as well. To be honest I kinda forgot how C++ works. I haven't touched C++ for a couple of years now so I made a lot of silly mistakes in it. Thanks though, I did realize that after I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most probably related to your implementation of quicksort. If you include the  header and use `std::sort` --which is not quicksort, but introsort, a variant that is meant to improve the worse case performance the results are quite different:

```
$ ./CompareSorts 
Quick Sort Took: 1
Selection Sort Took: 101
```

While running with your implementation of quicksort I am getting outputs similar to:

```
$ ./CompareSorts 
Quick Sort Took: 41
Selection Sort Took: 95
```

The hardware is a Core2-Duo 2GHz, and I compiled with `g++ -O3 -o CompareSorts CompareSorts.cpp` (note that the `-O3` is important: it tells gcc to optimize as much as it can).

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ code is fail. Firstly, the Standard already provides a quicksort- `std::sort`. Secondly, you picked a `std::vector`- for a statically sized array? Thirdly, `ftime` and the rest are *not* valid profiling timers. Thirdly, you keep returning values from `quicksort`, even though the function takes a reference- if you didn't set the optimization flags correctly this could destroy performance.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A(array_size);

    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand() % array_size;
    }

    __int64 begin, end, frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&begin);
    std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A));
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&end);
    std::cout << "Quick Sort Took: " << ((double)(end - begin) / frequency) * 1000 << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

0.7ms.

Comment: It's not statically sized. The size will be unknown in the final implementation of what I really want to use it for. This program was only made to test the time of it.

Comment: @Timlankey: I just edited to have a dynamically sized vector. It significantly *reduced* the running time on my machine. It doesn't change the fact that your code violates basic profiling principles- apart from the fact that such a synthetic benchmark is worthless anyway.

Comment: Thanks DeadMG, I learned a lot. I never really knew how to benchmark in C++. The code provided significantly helps with a lot of issues I have previously faced.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark B

You should also make sure :
- run each test on its own
- run each test several time to get an average
- use the same data for all the tests

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code causing this. In the Java version, you sort the array you receive while in the C++ version you sort the vector AND return a copy of it (you make an unecessary copy each recursion of the quicksort).

Don't forget to compile the C++ version with optimization (-O3).

Answer (score 0):

Mark B hit the nail on the head in this one. 
I repeated the test with the updated code on my rig with the results

> Java QS: 7ms
>
> Java SS: 111ms

vs

> C++ QS: 1ms
>
> C++ SS: 72ms